# Javascript or equals

Tags: equals

Below some javascript code that should check wether it's one of those letters or not. However when I type "Hallo" for example it also counts the 'H', 'L', 'L

```
woord.charAt(i) == 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'
```

What did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 7):

```
(woord.charAt(i) == 'a') || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u'
// evaluates to true or 'e'
```

It looks like you are trying to write code like you'd write a sentence, which doesn't translate well in this case. The above code shows what really happens with that expression.

You need to compare the character against each string individually or write a regular expression. The regex is more compact and would look like:

```
/[aeiou]/.test(word.charAt(i))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Since I'm pretty new to programming I couldn't use ur code. However I do understand it a bit.

Comment: @user1825015 The sooner you learn regex the better, string parsing will be quite a challenge until you do :)

Comment: Ye, just started ly 1st year of programming. Hope I will learn this 'Regex' quick. Since it makes the code a whole lot shorter.

Comment: @user1825015 No just shorter, more easy to modify as well (in case you ever decide to include 'y' for instance). There are plenty of tutorials out there. http://www.advanced-javascript-tutorial.com/RegularExpressions.cfm http://www.sitepoint.com/expressions-javascript/

Comment: I will definitely have a look to that site. Always handy to have short and easy code.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a different approach to the problem

```
    var c = woord.charAt(i);
    if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u'){
    vowels++;
    }
```

Comment: Casing issues, use toLowerCase()

Comment: Thanks, tried this. It did work and my code was a lot shorter.
Thanks mate

Comment: @user1825015 Make sure you use `var c = woord.charAt(i).toLowerCase();` or you won't match 'A','E','I','O','U' such as with "HELLO"

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead

```
var str = "My string";
var chr = "";
var nVowels = 0;

for (pos = 0; pos < str.length; pos++){
   chr = str.charAt(pos).toLowerCase();
   if (chr == "a" || chr == "e" || chr == "i" || chr == "o" || chr == "u")
    nVowels++;
}
```

Comment: Dear god... so many compares, and you could have used toLowerCase() to avoid the set of both upper and lower case compares. Even a switch case structure would look cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I forgot to add 'chr ==' after ||

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should be checking each option separately but this is ugly and doesn't perform too well. I would rather create an array of the accepted characters and check the index of the current char within that array.

```
var vowels = new Array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o');
var word = 'hello';
var vowelCount = 0;
for(var x=0; x < word.length; x++){
  var ch = word.charAt(x).toLowerCase();
  if (vowels.indexOf(ch) > -1)
    vowelCount++;
}
```